# Mathematica doesn't extract Re and Im parts properly

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex

I have a code:

```
θk = 0.1; kz = 2 π Sin[θk];

(*Cylindrical*)
A[mγ_, Λ_, x_, y_, z_, ϕ_, k_, ω_,t_] = Exp[-I (ω t - k Cos[θk] z + ϕ)] Sqrt[k Sin[θk]/(2 π)] ((Λ/Sqrt [2]) Exp[I mγ ArcTan[x, y]] Sin[θk] BesselJ[mγ, k Sin[θk] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] {0, 0, 1} +I^(-Λ) Exp[I (mγ - Λ) ArcTan[x, y]] Cos[θk/2]^2 BesselJ[mγ - Λ,k Sin[θk] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] {-Λ , -I, 0} +I^Λ Exp[I (mγ + Λ) ArcTan[x, y]] Sin[θk/2]^2 BesselJ[mγ + Λ,k Sin[θk] Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] {Λ, -I, 0});

(*Cartesian*)
ACart[mγ_, Λ_, x_, y_, z_, ϕ_,k_, ω_,t_] = {A[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[1]] Cos[ArcTan[x, y]] -A[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[2]] Sin[ArcTan[x, y]],A[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[1]] Sin[ArcTan[x, y]] +A[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[2]] Cos[ArcTan[x, y]],A[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[3]]};
Bc[mγ_, Λ_, x_, y_, z_, ϕ_, k_, ω_,t_] = {D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[3]], y] -D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[2]], z],D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[1]], z] -D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[3]], x],D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[2]], x] -D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t][[1]], y]};
Ec[mγ_, Λ_, x_, y_, z_, ϕ_, k_, ω_,t_] = -D[ACart[mγ, Λ, x, y, z, ϕ, k, ω,t], t];
l1 = 1; l2 = 2;
Elin[x_, y_, z_, Φ_, k1_, k2_, ω_, t_] = Ec[l1 + 1, 1, x, y, z, 0, k1, ω, t] - Ec[l1 - 1, -1, x, y, z, 0, k1, ω, t] + Ec[l2 + 1, 1, x, y, z, Φ, k2, ω, t] - Ec[l2 - 1, -1, x, y, z, Φ, k2, ω, t];
Blin[x_, y_, z_, Φ_, k1_, k2_, ω_, t_] = Bc[l1 + 1, 1, x, y, z, 0, k1, ω, t] -Bc[l1 - 1, -1, x, y, z, 0, k1, ω, t] + Bc[l2 + 1, 1, x, y, z, Φ, k2, ω, t] - Bc[l2 - 1, -1, x, y, z, Φ, k2, ω, t];
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Refine[Re[Elin[x, y, 0, 0, 2 π, 2 π, 2 π, 0]], {Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}]]]
```

I need it to take a proper `Im` and `Re` parts of `Elin` and `Blin` so that I could take partial derivatives afterwards, but it leaves stuff like `Re[BesselJ]` and `Arg[x + i y]` untreated no matter what I do. I have tried to put `Refine` in various places telling that x,y,z,k,$\phi$ etc. are all real, that $m_{\gamma}$ is integer... Nothing works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The documentation for `Arg` says: `Arg[z] is left unevaluated if z is not a numeric quantity` Since your x and y are not numeric I believe that explains why your `Arg[x+I y]` is not being further transformed. Can you state what you want `Arg[x+I y]` to be transformed into? Perhaps with that something can be done.

Comment: @Bill By def ArcTan[x,y], so that it could take a symbolic derivative of x or y properly afterwards

Comment: Please look at `Simplify[ComplexExpand[Elin[x,y,0,0,2 Pi,2 Pi,2 Pi,0] ]/.Arg[x+I y]->ArcTan[x,y],Element[x|y,Reals]]` and suggest what the next step needs to be.

Comment: @Bill It works as well, thanks!

Comment: Just in case you might be a little new at Mathematica, check the documentation for `ArcTan` which states `ArcTan[x,y] gives the arctangent of y/x` and that sometimes surprises new users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) option to [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
θk = 1/10; (* use exact value for parameter *)

ElinRe[x_, y_] = Assuming[Element[{x, y}, Reals],
  Elin[x, y, 0, 0, 2 π, 2 π, 2 π, 0] // Re //
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & //
   Simplify]

(* {π Sqrt[
  Sin[1/10]] ((1/(x^2 + y^2))
    BesselJ[1, 
      2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] (x^2 (-1 + Cos[1/10]) - 
       y^2 (1 + 3 Cos[1/10])) + (1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])
    2 (x BesselJ[0, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/20]^2 - 
       x BesselJ[4, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Cos[
         4 ArcTan[x, y]] Sin[1/20]^2 - 
       2 y BesselJ[2, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Cos[1/20]^2 Sin[
         2 ArcTan[x, y]] - 
       BesselJ[3, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/
         20]^2 (x Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]] - y Sin[3 ArcTan[x, y]]) + 
       y BesselJ[4, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/20]^2 Sin[
         4 ArcTan[x, y]])), (1/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)))
 2 π Sqrt[
  Sin[1/10]] (2 x y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
      BesselJ[1, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Cos[1/
      10] - (x^2 + 
       y^2) (-y BesselJ[0, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/20]^2 + 
       y BesselJ[4, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Cos[
         4 ArcTan[x, y]] Sin[1/20]^2 - 
       2 x BesselJ[2, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Cos[1/20]^2 Sin[
         2 ArcTan[x, y]] + 
       BesselJ[3, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/
         20]^2 (y Cos[3 ArcTan[x, y]] + x Sin[3 ArcTan[x, y]]) + 
       x BesselJ[4, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[1/20]^2 Sin[
         4 ArcTan[x, y]])), -(1/(x^2 + y^2))
  Sqrt[2] π Sin[1/10]^(
   3/2) (y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] BesselJ[1, 2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] + 
     2 x y BesselJ[2, 
       2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] + (x^2 + y^2) BesselJ[3, 
       2 π Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] Sin[1/10]] Sin[3 ArcTan[x, y]])} *)

Plot3D[
 Evaluate@ElinRe[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]